# What is the meaning of 早々となりで?

Tags: meaning

> 夢は夢だったということだけれど、戦いがはじまった早々となりで死なれたら寝ざめが悪い (novel: *All You Need Is Kill*)

I understand that the sentence means something along the lines of : "dream it was however if he died at the start of the battle it will leave a bitter taste in my mouse ."

What does なりで add here? Why is it not just  早々と ?

Comment: 戦いがはじまった早々／となりで死なれたら.

Comment: Forgot to add 早々 is そうそう.

Comment: I think this could still trigger a decent answer about 早々 independently of the mis-reading, however as it stands I think this would need editing to get there.

Answer (score 2):

This [早々](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%97%A9%E3%80%85) is yet another noun that can form a subordinate clause. Just as 始まった時 means "when it starts" and 始まった瞬間 means "the moment it starts", 始まった早々 means "soon after it starts" or "not too long after it starts". 早々 can optionally take に, and the verb before it can be a te-form (e.g., 始まった早々 = 始まった早々に = 始まって早々 = 始まって早々に).

早々 never takes と, and this となりで is 隣で ("next to me").